# ¿Como podría obtener el ultimo lunes de cada mes en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito saber como obtendría el ultimo lunes de cada mes, ya que en el programa que tengo que hacer, ese ultimo lunes de cada mes debo generar un interés, pero no se como podría calcularlo.

intente obtener los dias totales del mes y restar 7 dias pero obviamente el resultado no siempre será un lunes.

```
  DateTime fechaHoy = (DateTime)fechahoy.Value.Date;
  DateTime fechabono = FechaAbono.Value.Date;


  int anyo = fechabono.Year;
  int mes = fechabono.Month;
  int dias = DateTime.DaysInMonth(anyo, mes);

  int anyoHoy = fechaHoy.Year;
  int mesHoy = fechaHoy.Month;
  int diasHoy = DateTime.DaysInMonth(anyoHoy, mesHoy);

  int totaldiashoy = DateTime.DaysInMonth(anyoHoy, mesHoy);// 31 dias
  int totaldias = totaldiashoy - 7;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si quieres saber el número de día Lunes del mes, usa la siguiente función:

```
//Ultimo lunes: retorna valor entero
public int  UltimoLunesDelMes(int anio, int mes)
{
   var ulimoLunesDelMes = new DateTime(anio, mes, DateTime.DaysInMonth(anio,mes));
                
                 //es un loop pequeño sin problemas de performance
                while (ulimoLunesDelMes.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    ulimoLunesDelMes = ulimoLunesDelMes.AddDays(-1);

   return  ulimoLunesDelMes.Day;            
}

//Ejemplo: ultimo lunes de enero del 2019
  var diaUltimo = UltimoLunesDelMes(2019, 1); //28
```

Saludos

Answer (score 17):

Las respuestas que has recibido hacen uso de un bucle. Yo voy a añadir una que no, y además es genérico para buscar cualquier día de la semana. Simplemente se calcula el último día del mes, y con el día de la semana que sea se calcula cual es el anterior dia de la semana que nos interese.

Esto funciona porque la enumeración [DayOfWeek](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2) asigna un entero a cada día de la semana, siendo el Domingo 0 y así hasta el Sábado que es 6.

```
private DateTime ObtenerUltimoDiaSemanaDelMes(int anio,int mes, System.DayOfWeek dia)
{
    DateTime ultimoDiaMes = new DateTime(anio, mes, DateTime.DaysInMonth(anio, mes));
    int diferencia = ultimoDiaMes.DayOfWeek - dia;
    return diferencia> 0 ? ultimoDiaMes.AddDays(-1 * diferencia) : ultimoDiaMes.AddDays(-1 * (7 + diferencia));
}
```

La forma de llamarlo es la siguiente:

```
DateTime ultimoLunes = ObtenerUltimoDiaSemanaDelMes(2019, 12, DayOfWeek.Monday);
DateTime ultimoMiercoles = ObtenerUltimoDiaSemanaDelMes(2019, 12, DayOfWeek.Wednesday);
```

Answer (score 8):

El último lunes de cualquier mes sería:

```
fecha.AddDays(-(double)fecha.DayOfWeek + 1);
```

Cuando `fecha` es el último día del mes (y asumiendo que el lunes vale `1` y el domingo vale `0`). Ahora tu problema es obtener el último día del mes, que es tan sencillo como ir al primer día del mes siguiente y restar un día:

```
var ultimoDiaEnero = (new DateTime(2019, 2, 1)).AddDays(-1);
```

Asi que, el último lunes de Enero 2019 fue:

```
var ultimoDiaEnero = (new DateTime(2019, 2, 1)).AddDays(-1);
Console.WriteLine(ultimoDiaEnero.AddDays(-(double)ultimoDiaEnero.DayOfWeek + 1));
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1/28/2019 12:00:00 AM
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Una forma de hacerlo sería primero obteniendo la última semana del mes que quieres obtener, y después obtener el lunes de ésa semana de la siguiente forma:

```
private DateTime GetLastMondayOfMonth(int year, int month)
{
    return FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(year, GetLastWeekOfMonth(year, month));
}

private int GetLastWeekOfMonth(int year, int month)
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    //Creamos un DateTime con el año, el mes y los dias totales de ése mes
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));

    Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
    //Obtenemos la semana de la fecha creada anteriormente
    return cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, dfi.CalendarWeekRule,
                                        dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
}

public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeekISO8601(int year, int weekOfYear)
{
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;

    // Usamos el primer Lunes de Enero para obtener la primera semana del año que no sea la semana 52/53/54 del año anterior
    DateTime firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
    int firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);

    var weekNum = weekOfYear;
    // Como estamos agregando días a una fecha en la semana 1, 
    // debemos restar 1 para obtener la fecha correcta para la semana # 1
    if (firstWeek == 1)
    {
        weekNum -= 1;
    }

    // Usar el primer Jueves como semana de inicio garantiza que comencemos en el año correcto
    // luego sumamos el número de semanas multiplicado por días.
    var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);

    // Restamos 3 dias al Jueves para obtener el Lunes que es el primer dia de la semana segun la ISO8601
    return result.AddDays(-3);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

lo que podes hacer recorrer los días hacia atrás (*por una cuestión de eficiencia*) y el primer lunes que encuentras es tu último lunes del mes:

```
public DateTime? ObtenerUltimoLunesDelMes(int anyo, int mes)
{
    var diasEnElMes = DateTime.DaysInMonth(anyo, mes);

    for (int dia = diasEnElMes; dia > 0; dia--)
    {
        DateTime actual = new DateTime(anyo, mes, dia);
        if (actual.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            return actual;
    }

    return null;
}
```